# Quantum computing and string theory: which path should I pursue first?

Tags: string-theory, education, quantum-computer

I'm an undergraduate physics student waiting for responses from graduate programs I applied to. I apologize if this question is slightly off-topic for physics SE, but I really want to hear some advice about the path I should pursue first to achieve my long-term goal.

I applied to Ph.D. programs in quantum information, as well as master's programs in mathematical physics, with a focus on string theory. I'm fascinated with the prospect of solving questions in fundamental physics through quantum computing. Recently I've been reading about [some research](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.06573) that combined these two fields.

My undergraduate study and research experiences introduced me to the basics of quantum mechanics and quantum simulation. I think the PhD program would definitely allow me to deepen my understanding of this field. However, I don't have a very strong background in mathematical physics and haven't been introduced to string theory. So I'm worried if there's no relevant course in PhD program, whether I would still have a chance to learn about string theory.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice about how I can connect quantum computing with fundamental physics, or the path I should pursue first in this case.

Comment: Advice from an old experimental physicist. If you are interested in doing research that connects quantum computing with string theories, I propose to start with acquiring expertise in computations of string theories  and then go to quantum computing. If you enter a PhD track in quantum computing most of your studies and effort would go there and it is doubtful you would have the time to delve into string theory courses.

Comment: @anna v Thank you!!